# Bootable External Drive Issue on Apple Silicon M2- Need Help Resolving

Tags: mac, external-hard-drive, restore, disk-cloning, macos-monterey

Note: **It is working Fine on M1 machine.**

I've been encountering difficulties with my bootable external drive on my Apple Silicon Mac.

I've tried creating the bootable drive using ASR, Carbon Copy Cloner, and SuperDuper,

but unfortunately, the system doesn't boot up, displaying an error message indicating that the OS needs to be reinstalled on the selected disk.

Here are the steps I've taken so far:

- Checked compatibility:

Ensured macOS version on the external drive is compatible with Apple Silicon.
Recreated the bootable drive: Used ASR, Carbon Copy Cloner, and SuperDuper to recreate the bootable external drive.

- Reset NVRAM/PRAM:

Attempted to resolve the issue by resetting NVRAM/PRAM.
Checked external drive connection: Ensured proper connection and tried different ports and cables.

- Updated macOS:

Updated the macOS version on the external drive to the latest.

- Checked for errors:

Ran Disk Utility from Recovery Mode to check and repair any disk-related issues.

Despite these efforts, the problem persists. The external drive is formatted with the APFS file system, and I've verified that the cloning tools are up to date. I would appreciate any insights or suggestions from the community on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Has anyone else experienced a similar problem with bootable external drives on Apple Silicon, and if so, how did you successfully address it?

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration.
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/469207/bootable-external-drive-issue-on-apple-silicon-m2-need-help-resolving

Comment: Checking compatibility requires more than just checking the processor architecture. Macs can never boot from an earlier release of macOS than the exact version that that model shipped with. So questions like this need to include the exact model identifier and the exact OS version tried. Saying "Sonoma on some M2 Mac" is not enough detail of either the OS or the hardware.

Comment: Have you tried updating the local OS on the mac to the latest version first? This may well apply a much needed firmware update to the mac hardware, and you might find after doing this that you're then able to boot off the version that resides on your external drive. Just a wild guess!